# do I have to opening port 443/80 locally to browse internet?

Tags: request, port

if I want to browse internet through https, do I have to open port 443? I though the only port should open for https is on server side. same question here, I also need to open port 80 for sending and receiving http request?

Answer (score 1):

No. You should not need to open port 80 or 443 to make web requests. You should only need to open up ports if you plan to have other computers make new connections in to your computer (for example, if you are setting up a web server that will host content for others).

Comment: just realize there is difference between source port and destination port. so when sending request, client pick a random port between 10204 and 65536 and send to port 80(http) or 443(https) on server depends on what protocol servers use. for instance, google use https, then client sends request to port 443 to google server, yahoo use http, client sends request to port 80.